# How to prevent emails from being created in record chatter after sending email to customer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-14

I would like to send an email (using template) to customer but I don't want to create said email in record chatter as well.

Right now I use the method `send_mail()` from `mail.mail_template`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to send email via Odoo core Email wizard, then it is not possible because the "composition_mode" field is required and default value is comment.

But if you can achieve it with a new custom button, type=object. On the button click, the method will trigger in the background, fetch an email template and send it.